# Removing from listbox and database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, listbox

This is my Form1.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VoetbalApp
{
    public partial class VoetbalApp : Form
{
    Administration admin = new Administration();

    public VoetbalApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadSpelers();
    }


    public void LoadSpelers()
    {


        string filter = tbNaam.Text;
        lbSpelers.Items.Clear();

        List<Speler> spelers = admin.GetAllSpelers(filter);

        foreach (Speler s in spelers.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(filter)))
        {
            lbSpelers.Items.Add(s);
        }

    }

    public bool ClubCorrect(string club)
    {

        if (club != "Unitas 59")
        { 
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string spelerNaam = tbAddNaam.Text;
        string spelerClub = tbAddClub.Text;

        if (ClubCorrect(spelerClub))
        {
           admin.AddSpeler(spelerNaam, spelerClub);

            LoadSpelers();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("De door u ingevoerde club is niet juist."
                );
        }
    }

    private void btDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id;
        Int32.TryParse(tbId.Text, out id);

        bool verwijderenIsGelukt = admin.RemoveSpeler(id);

        if (verwijderenIsGelukt)
        {
            LoadSpelers();
            MessageBox.Show("Speler met ID" + id + " is succesvol verwijderd.");
            tbId.Text = "";
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Er is iets mis gegaan bij het verwijderen van student met ID" + id + ".", "Verwijderen is mislukt.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void tbNaam_TextChanged(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSpelers();
    }

    private void tbNaam_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSpelers();
    }


}
}
```

And my second code is Administration.cs

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data;

 // For SQL server operations
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace VoetbalApp
 {

class Administration
{


    public static string connectionString = @"Initial Catalog=Speler.mdf;Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Speler.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);






    List<Speler> spelers = new List<Speler>();


    /// <param name="name">De naam van de nieuwe speler.</param>
    /// <param name="club">De club van de nieuwe speler.</param>
    /// 


    public void AddSpeler(string name, string club)
    {

            conn.Open();
            Speler speler = new Speler();
            speler.Name = name;
            speler.Club = club;
            string query = @"INSERT INTO Speler (Name, Club) OUTPUT Inserted.ID 
                 VALUES (@name, @club)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = speler.Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@club", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = speler.Club;
            speler.ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();


    }





    /// <param name="ID">Het ID van de speler die verwijderd moet worden.</param>
    /// <returns>Geeft true terug bij succes, en anders false.</returns>
    public bool RemoveSpeler(int ID)
    {
        int nrOfRowsAffected = 0;


        conn.Open();
            foreach (Speler s in spelers)
            {

                if (s.ID == ID)
                {

                    string query = "DELETE FROM Speler WHERE ID = " + ID;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);


                    nrOfRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    spelers.Remove(s);


                    break;
                }
            }


        conn.Close();
        return nrOfRowsAffected > 0;
    }


    /// <param name="filter">De filter is om spelers te zoeken van de database.</param>
    /// <returns>Een lijst van spelers waarvoor de filter is toegepast.</returns>
    public List<Speler> GetAllSpelers(string filter)
    {



        spelers = new List<Speler>();


        string query = "SELECT S.* FROM Speler S";



        if (filter != "")
        {
            query += " WHERE Name LIKE '%" + filter + "%' OR Club LIKE '%" + filter + "%'";
        }



        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);


        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                Speler speler = new Speler();


                speler.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                speler.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                speler.Club = reader.GetString(2);


                spelers.Add(speler);
            }
        }


        conn.Close();
        return spelers;

    }
}
}
```

So the issue is at the **RemoveSpeler** at administration.cs and **btDelete** in form1.cs. Thanks for taking your time.
I have mostly code in my post so i need to add more details or i cant post it so..
So the thing I want to do is that I have a textbox (tbID) where I need to put the number of the ID of the Speler and then press a button (btDelete) to remove the Speler with the ID i entered, from the listbox/database. But for some reason It just doesn't do anything, no error or anything.
And this still isn't enough detail so I still can't post it so I Just have to type more stuff here, i dont know what else to type here.

Comment: Your first line of code was not in the grey background thingy because it must start with 4 consecutive spaces to be considered a part of the code.

Comment: Also, you should use parameters instead of concatenating strings to create your sql statements. Read about SQL Injection.

Comment: Is `speler` deleted from list?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in click handler for the delete button then stepping through to see what is being executed? For example, does the RemoveSpeler method get called? Does the database connection get opened? Is the SQL command executed? And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public static class admin
    {
        public static bool RemoveSpeller(int id, ListBox listbox)
        {

            if (listbox.Items.Contains(id.ToString()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exists");
                listbox.Items.Remove(id.ToString());
                try
                {

                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(/*Connection string goes here*/);

                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Speler WHERE id = '" + id + "'", con);

                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
                    return true;

                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong while removing the item");
                    return false;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wasn't found!");
                return false;
            }


        }
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           admin.RemoveSpeller(Convert.ToInt16(tbId.Text), yourlistboxname);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Function returns bool value `return nrOfRowsAffected > 0;` in question.

Comment: I have my first code in a different class so I when I try your code and put the RemoveFromDataBase code in my other class and the button1_click in my main code It gives me an error at     (listbox.Items.IndexOf(**id**)));      The name 'id' doesn't exist in this context and the other one is at     if (**rowsaffected** == 1)    and it gives the same error as the id one.

Comment: Ok I separated the code for each class! Rename wherever it says Class1 with your class as well as all the controls with your controls names!

Comment: This one doens't seem to work at all, It can't even create the SqlConnection for some reason. I have my orignal SqlConnection in a different class and thats why this code doesn't really work because I can't call some of these items

Comment: Get the code I renamed everything but the listbox because I don't know it's name, rename the yourlistboxname with your listbox

Comment: I just posted my complete code, its a mess because its so much code I had to enter allot of text, sorry.

Comment: Your new one seems allot better, only one error "Member 'Administration.RemoveSpeler(int, ListBox)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead" Any idea?

Comment: Remove static from RemoveSpeller function!
Administration.RemoveSpeller(Convert.ToInt16(tbId.Text), yourlistboxname);

Comment: It's error free now, but for some reason it still doens't do anything just like before. No errors but it doesnt remove anything either...

Comment: Do you have teamviewer?

Comment: Yes how do you want me to send you my ID and password?

Comment: email me at thanosage@yahoo.com or find me on facebook Thanos Ageridis